# Simple library to display 2D images in C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface

I would like to have a tool to debug 2D planar meshes. I would like to be able to display them and debug to be able to debug certain things.

Is there a widget (for any toolkit on Linux - QT, GTK+Cairo, ...) which would display the images, scroll them and zoom it. Is there any widget which would handle it (without need to implement zooming, scrolling etc. by hand)?

Side requirements:

- Needs to work on CentOS 6
- I need it for C++. Unfortunately changing the build system in my situation is harder then it sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Qt Graphics View](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/graphicsview.html) is certainly a useful tool, it gives you scrolling, zooming, rotating easily. You probably want to learn the basics of Qt before. (and Qt is in C++).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an off the wall suggestion.

This would be fairly easy to implement in a web browser. Web browser engines already have the base functionality for resizing and scrolling over images. You may need a little JavaScript to bind it together, of course.

So why not use [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/)? There are bindings for many of the leading toolkits (e.g. QWebView for Qt), so you could take your pick of which one you're most comfortable with.

Yes, it's overkill. But it's code you don't have to write, and time is money.

Comment: Then, you might suggest to Maciej to make his app a web application (e.g. using FastCGI or Wt http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt ...); however, that means learning Javascript....

Comment: One of the thoughts I had is that you could prototype the functionality of the application in a web browser in about half an hour. You wouldn't have to know very much JavaScript to do this.

Another thought that I had was that if your texture was tiled and mipmapped, there are JavaScript apps already out there which handle it all for you, such as Google Maps.

Comment: The project already is in two languages. Adding yet another one just to have visual debugging of data is overkill. In worst case I can just write an image file. (As of prototyping - thanks for suggestion but for several reasons JavaScript is not a good language for the project)